# Visual Studio C++ - show function code on mouse hover like in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, intellisense

I am looking for some extension or option for Visual Studio (2015) in C++ that will make something like this:

- When I hover over function name it will popup some box with a function definition.
- When I hover over structure it will popup box with structure's members.

Eclipse (at least Neon) has something exactly like this. This image presents what I'm talking about (you can even scroll this popup box):

[image]

Comment: Great! Peek definition is exactly what I was looking for. I've changed shortcut to better one I don't need hover. Def. win is also good, but do you know how to change font size in def. win. but not in editor?

Comment: @BoPersson, could you please add a reply with your comment when you have free time? Since it is solved zupazt3's issue and it is easy for other community member to search this useful information.

Comment: @zupazt3, if Bo Persson add a reply, please mark it as answer and it will helpful for other community members who have the same question to easier search this information. BTW, usually we discuss one question in one thread, you can try to create a new thread for your new question, it will more obvious for us to research and discuss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I didn't think this exactly answered the question, but from the comments it's apparently close enough:*

Hovering does something else, but you can right-click and select Peek Definition to get the popup. Or have a Code Definition Window open and left-click the name.

Unfortunately I don't know how to change the text size in the "View"-windows, just in the main editing window.